# error in program on site but not on codeblocks

Tags: c, arrays, codeblocks

I am doing competition coding and on the site i.e. hacker my program gives the "error control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]" but on codeblocks it is working fine here is my code.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int count_max_freq(int *a,int n,int i)
{   static int max_freq=0,index;
    int t=a[i],f=0;
    for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        if(a[i]==a[j])
            f++;
    if(max_freq<f)
    {   max_freq=f;
        index=i;
    }
    if(i<n)
        count_max_freq(a,n,i+1);
    else
        return a[index];
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int *types = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int types_i = 0; types_i < n; types_i++){
       scanf("%d",&types[types_i]);
    }
    // your code goes here
    printf("%d",count_max_freq(types,n,0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to fix that: `if(i<n)
        count_max_freq(a,n,i+1);` => `if(i<n)
        return count_max_freq(a,n,i+1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those return paths does not return anything (the recursive one) hence the warning.

The fact that it works is mere luck (not sure what you're calling working: "it compiles" doesn't mean "it runs properly", well it *could* by mere luck but I wouldn't bet on it)

My suggestion: replace that:

```
if(i<n)
    count_max_freq(a,n,i+1);  // should return the value!
else
    return a[index];
```

by a ternary expression so you only have one return statement, no warning, and it works everywhere:

```
return (i<n) ? count_max_freq(a,n,i+1) : a[index];
```

Comment: On many systems it's a bit more than luck - the compiler would have to do extra work to clear the result of the last function call from the return register before returning.